# Return special JsonResult in case of Exception occurs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception

```
public JsonResult Menu() { // Exception }
```

I need application not to redirect user to the 404 page, but return special JSON result like { "result":1 }.
I wonder, is there any another solution, not try-catching.

Comment: What is not working? What does an exception have to do with a 404 Resource Not Found?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement your own `FilterAttribute` similar to the `HandleErrorAttribute`.

The HandleErrorAttribute normally does a redirect when an error occurs, but you could implement a similar attribute that returns a JsonResult. Something like the following will do:

```
public class CustomHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }

        filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
        {
            Data = new { result = 1 },
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

And then

```
[CustomHandleError]
public JsonResult Menu()
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

I would recommend that you [download the MVC source code from CodePlex](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MVC&referringTitle=Home) and inspect the current implementation of `HandleErrorAttribute`. It is a lot more subtle than my crude implementation above and you may want some of its functionality.